# Start perfectlightbox gallery per textlink

Tags: jquery, lightbox, typo3

I have another typo3/jquery problem now with the extension perfectlightbox.

I want to open my image gallery (several images with `rel="lightbox[lb5]"`) with a textlink.
The gallery should start with the first image, so thats my textlink

```
<a href="/uploads/pics/image_01.jpg" rel="lightbox[lb5]">more images &gt;</a>
```

The Problem is, that the first image is now twice in the gallery.

ps: the server with the perfectlightbox reference is down at the moment, so I couldn't look there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a solution, thx anyway, here is my solution: I call a function on my textlink which simulates a click on the image:

```
$('a[rel="lightbox[lb' + no + ']"]').first().trigger("click");
```